# Talking about accepted offer in job interview

Tags: interview

I accepted an offer and after that got an iterview opportunity from my dream company. In the interview they had asked me if I have deadlines coming up. I informed them that I had to accept another offer since the deadline was before they invited me to the interview.
Will this create a negative opinion with interviewer or HR? Will the decision of considering me for next rounds be affected?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are interviewing at companies, why are you asking this on Academia.SE?

Comment: Is this company an academic entity? I am not sure why it's posted here and not in [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you accept an offer you should immediately withdraw from consideration from all other potential employers. This is simply to preserve your own credibility for the future. Failing to do this will, perhaps, cause them to expend resources wastefully and it can come back on you in the future.

They won't want to talk to you in the future if they think you might do this again in the middle of negotiations.

Alternatively, you can back out of your earlier acceptance if possible so that you are really available. This is risky, of course. But this is a situation that if you try to play games, you will probably lose.

Answer (score 1):

Surely by saying you have accepted another offer somewhere else, you have simply told them you don't want their offer.

Comment: I also mentioned that I am very much interested in their company. The interview invitation was sent after the offer deadline.  Won't this be considered?

Comment: *The interview invitation was sent after the offer deadline.* --- This is not the problem that others here are having with your actions. You said "In the interview they had asked me ...", which means you went through with the interview AFTER having accepted an offer elsewhere. Doing this without telling the company you have already accepted another offer (when you were arranging an interview with them) is the problem that others here are having with your actions. The time to tell them that you have accepted another offer, but are very interested in them, is when they made the invitation.